# How to avoid Module Search Path errors in python?

Tags: python, import, module

I feel like I have read numerous posts at this point about ModuleNotFoundError errors in python, and I try to include everything needed to avoid them, but it seems like sheer luck when I finally pull off an import of my own package. I'm hoping for some clarity.

Right now I have a file system such as the following:

```
main.ipynb
scripts/
----__init__.py
----processing.py
----graph.py
----ml.py
```

I have modified sys.path to contain the directory that main.ipynb is in and the scripts directory.

I have autoreload turned on.

I confirmed that sys.path is complete and contains all directories necessary (and probably more than necessary) and that my computer is seeing the **init**.py file without additional extensions.

But if I run the following:

```
from scripts.processing import *
from scripts.ml import *
from scripts.graph import *
```

I get a ModuleNotFound error. What am I doing wrong here?

edit: If I name the module myscripts, everything works fine. Is scripts a built-in python module that clobbers my local module?

Comment: If you just run the code you have shown, you have *not* modified sys.path. Where is the code that modifies it?

Comment: What do you get if you run `import scripts; print(scripts.__file__)`? Is it your local module?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I didn't include the sys.path.append('...') code because I didn't want to reveal the servers file structure

Comment: @mkrieger1 if I run `import scripts; print(scripts.__file__)' I see the following: /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scripts/__init__.py. Good catch! It seems like there is in fact a python built-in module named scripts and that was the issue after all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.